# placing multiple HTML5 canvas elements on a page

Tags: html, web-applications, html5-canvas

I made a beat machine in HTML5
http://optiq-customtees.zxq.net/Beat_Machine_Sample.html

What I need to figure out is how I can break down the different elements and place them on top of each other.  I want to have the screen and buttons as separate html5 drawings placed on top of the main box and made interactive so people can click on them.

So I want to place this
http://optiq-customtees.zxq.net/Beat_Machine_Box.html

Then place this in the corner
http://optiq-customtees.zxq.net/Beat_Machine_Screen.html

Then space this out 16 times
http://optiq-customtees.zxq.net/Beat_Machine_Button.html

How can I accomplish this?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

**How to turn your mock-up into a working pad**

[image]

You already have the functions for drawing the body, screen and  a button.

So the task becomes:

- Make the button drawing code reusable so all 12 buttons can be drawn easily.
- Listen for user mouseclicks and report which button was pressed.

Here's how to accomplish those tasks.

**Draw Multiple Buttons using the same button drawing function**

First you need to calculate some basic information about the button drawing:

```
    // calculate button properties

    var buttonOffsetX=44.9;
    var buttonOffsetY=210.6;
    var buttonWidth=139.4-44.9;
    var buttonHeight=305.1-210.3;
    var buttonPadding=15;
```

Make the button drawing reusable by putting it in a function.

```
    function drawOneButton(left,top) {

            …draw one button at left/top

    }
```

Then call that function and send the X/Y coordinates where the button is to be drawn:

```
    // calculate where the button will go (left and top)

    var leftX=buttonOffsetX+x*(buttonWidth+buttonPadding);
    var topY=buttonOffsetY+y*(buttonHeight+buttonPadding);

    // call on drawOneButton to draw a button

    drawOneButton(leftX,topY);
```

Putting it all together…

Here’s code that will draw all the buttons on the pad using loops:

```
    // draw the 4x3 grid of buttons

    for(var x=0;x<4;x++){
        for(var y=0;y<3;y++){
            drawOneButton(buttonOffsetX+x*(buttonWidth +buttonPadding),
                          buttonOffsetY+y*(buttonHeight+buttonPadding));
        }
    }
```

Now task#2...

**Listen for user mouseclicks and report which button was pressed**

You can use jQuery to listen for when the user clicks on your pad:

```
    // listen when the use clicks the mouse
    // when they do, call the function handleMouseDown

    $("#canvas").mousedown(function(e){handleMouseDown(e);});
```

The handleMouseDown function calculates and displays which button was pressed:

```
      var col=parseInt((mouseX-buttonOffsetX)/(buttonWidth+buttonPadding));
      var row=parseInt((mouseY-buttonOffsetY)/(buttonHeight+buttonPadding));
```

So putting it all together...

Here's the full handleMouseDown function that's called when the user clicks the mouse:

- Calculate the mouse position (mouseX/mouseY)
- Calculate which button is under that mouse position
- Report which button was pressed

  ```
  function handleMouseDown(e){
    mouseX=parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX);
    mouseY=parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY);

    // Put your mousedown stuff here
    var col=parseInt((mouseX-buttonOffsetX)/(buttonWidth+buttonPadding));
    var row=parseInt((mouseY-buttonOffsetY)/(buttonHeight+buttonPadding));
    $("#row").html("Row: "+row);
    $("#col").html("Col: "+col);
  }
  ```

**This button calculation is just to get your started**

You should modify the code to ignore when the user clicks but doesn't click on a button.

And, of course, you must write code to respond to any button presses.

Here is code and a Fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/98ZgL/

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/reset.css" /> <!-- reset css -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>

<style>
    body{ background-color: ivory; padding:7px;}
    #canvas{border:1px solid red;}
    h3{font-size:2em;}
</style>

<script>
$(function(){

    var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");

    var canvasOffset=$("#canvas").offset();
    var offsetX=canvasOffset.left;
    var offsetY=canvasOffset.top;


    function handleMouseDown(e){
      mouseX=parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX);
      mouseY=parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY);

      // Put your mousedown stuff here
      var col=parseInt((mouseX-buttonOffsetX)/(buttonWidth+buttonPadding));
      var row=parseInt((mouseY-buttonOffsetY)/(buttonHeight+buttonPadding));
      $("#row").html("Row: "+row);
      $("#col").html("Col: "+col);
    }


    // calculate button properties
    var buttonOffsetX=44.9;
    var buttonOffsetY=210.6;
    var buttonWidth=139.4-44.9;
    var buttonHeight=305.1-210.3;
    var buttonPadding=15;

    // draw the gray background
    drawBackground();

    // draw the teal screen
    drawScreen();

    // draw the 4x3 grid of buttons
    for(var x=0;x<4;x++){
        for(var y=0;y<3;y++){
            drawOneButton(buttonOffsetX+x*(buttonWidth+buttonPadding),buttonOffsetY+y*(buttonHeight+buttonPadding));
        }
    }

    // listen for mousedown (when user presses a button)
    $("#canvas").mousedown(function(e){handleMouseDown(e);});



    function drawOneButton(left,top) {

      // layer1/Path
      ctx.save();

      // translate to top-left where button will be placed
      ctx.translate(left-44.9,top-210.6);

      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.moveTo(138.2, 303.9);
      ctx.lineTo(46.1, 303.9);
      ctx.lineTo(46.1, 211.8);
      ctx.lineTo(138.2, 211.8);
      ctx.lineTo(138.2, 303.9);
      ctx.closePath();
      ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(0, 41, 118)";
      ctx.fill();

      // layer1/Path
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.moveTo(138.2, 303.9);
      ctx.lineTo(46.1, 303.9);
      ctx.lineTo(46.1, 211.8);
      ctx.lineTo(50.5, 211.8);
      ctx.lineTo(50.5, 299.6);
      ctx.lineTo(138.2, 299.6);
      ctx.lineTo(138.2, 303.9);
      ctx.closePath();
      ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(0, 16, 118)";
      ctx.fill();

      // layer1/Path
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.moveTo(46.1, 211.8);
      ctx.lineTo(138.2, 211.8);
      ctx.lineTo(138.2, 303.9);
      ctx.lineTo(133.9, 299.6);
      ctx.lineTo(133.9, 216.1);
      ctx.lineTo(50.5, 216.1);
      ctx.lineTo(46.1, 211.8);
      ctx.closePath();
      ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(0, 71, 188)";
      ctx.fill();

      // layer1/Compound Path
      ctx.beginPath();

      // layer1/Compound Path/Path
      ctx.moveTo(139.4, 305.1);
      ctx.lineTo(44.9, 305.1);
      ctx.lineTo(44.9, 210.6);
      ctx.lineTo(139.4, 210.6);
      ctx.lineTo(139.4, 305.1);
      ctx.closePath();

      // layer1/Compound Path/Path
      ctx.moveTo(47.3, 302.7);
      ctx.lineTo(137.1, 302.7);
      ctx.lineTo(137.1, 212.9);
      ctx.lineTo(47.3, 212.9);
      ctx.lineTo(47.3, 302.7);
      ctx.closePath();
      ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(0, 0, 103)";
      ctx.fill();
      ctx.restore();
    }



    function drawScreen() {

      // layer1/Path
      ctx.save();
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.moveTo(38.2, 78.5);
      ctx.lineTo(283.4, 78.5);
      ctx.lineTo(283.4, 171.2);
      ctx.lineTo(275.2, 164.3);
      ctx.lineTo(274.0, 86.7);
      ctx.lineTo(46.7, 85.5);
      ctx.lineTo(38.2, 78.5);
      ctx.closePath();
      ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(104, 104, 104)";
      ctx.fill();

      // layer1/Group

      // layer1/Group/Path
      ctx.save();
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.moveTo(274.6, 163.7);
      ctx.lineTo(47.1, 163.7);
      ctx.lineTo(47.1, 86.0);
      ctx.lineTo(274.6, 86.0);
      ctx.lineTo(274.6, 163.7);
      ctx.closePath();
      ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(66, 160, 160)";
      ctx.fill();

      // layer1/Group/Compound Path
      ctx.beginPath();

      // layer1/Group/Compound Path/Path
      ctx.moveTo(275.7, 164.8);
      ctx.lineTo(45.9, 164.8);
      ctx.lineTo(45.9, 84.8);
      ctx.lineTo(275.7, 84.8);
      ctx.lineTo(275.7, 164.8);
      ctx.closePath();

      // layer1/Group/Compound Path/Path
      ctx.moveTo(48.3, 162.5);
      ctx.lineTo(273.4, 162.5);
      ctx.lineTo(273.4, 87.2);
      ctx.lineTo(48.3, 87.2);
      ctx.lineTo(48.3, 162.5);
      ctx.closePath();
      ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(0, 0, 0)";
      ctx.fill();

      // layer1/Compound Path
      ctx.restore();
      ctx.beginPath();

      // layer1/Compound Path/Path
      ctx.moveTo(284.6, 172.3);
      ctx.lineTo(37.0, 172.3);
      ctx.lineTo(37.0, 77.3);
      ctx.lineTo(284.6, 77.3);
      ctx.lineTo(284.6, 172.3);
      ctx.closePath();

      // layer1/Compound Path/Path
      ctx.moveTo(39.4, 170.0);
      ctx.lineTo(282.2, 170.0);
      ctx.lineTo(282.2, 79.7);
      ctx.lineTo(39.4, 79.7);
      ctx.lineTo(39.4, 170.0);
      ctx.closePath();
      ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(0, 0, 0)";
      ctx.fill();
      ctx.restore();
    }



    function drawBackground() {

      // layer1/Group
      ctx.save();

      // layer1/Group/Path
      ctx.save();
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.moveTo(1.9, 41.3);
      ctx.lineTo(45.8, 1.2);
      ctx.lineTo(468.7, 1.2);
      ctx.lineTo(510.5, 41.3);
      ctx.lineTo(306.2, 235.4);
      ctx.lineTo(1.9, 41.3);
      ctx.closePath();
      ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(81, 81, 81)";
      ctx.fill();

      // layer1/Group/Compound Path
      ctx.beginPath();

      // layer1/Group/Compound Path/Path
      ctx.moveTo(306.4, 236.9);
      ctx.lineTo(305.6, 236.4);
      ctx.lineTo(0.0, 41.4);
      ctx.lineTo(45.4, 0.0);
      ctx.lineTo(469.2, 0.0);
      ctx.lineTo(512.2, 41.3);
      ctx.lineTo(511.3, 42.1);
      ctx.lineTo(306.4, 236.9);
      ctx.closePath();

      // layer1/Group/Compound Path/Path
      ctx.moveTo(3.8, 41.1);
      ctx.lineTo(306.1, 233.9);
      ctx.lineTo(508.8, 41.3);
      ctx.lineTo(468.2, 2.3);
      ctx.lineTo(46.3, 2.3);
      ctx.lineTo(3.8, 41.1);
      ctx.closePath();
      ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(0, 0, 0)";
      ctx.fill();

      // layer1/Path
      ctx.restore();
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.moveTo(510.5, 549.8);
      ctx.lineTo(1.9, 549.8);
      ctx.lineTo(1.9, 41.3);
      ctx.lineTo(510.5, 41.3);
      ctx.lineTo(510.5, 549.8);
      ctx.closePath();
      ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(131, 131, 131)";
      ctx.fill();

      // layer1/Path
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.moveTo(342.5, 181.0);
      ctx.bezierCurveTo(474.6, 299.1, 510.5, 549.8, 510.5, 549.8);
      ctx.lineTo(510.5, 41.3);
      ctx.lineTo(1.9, 41.3);
      ctx.bezierCurveTo(1.9, 41.3, 210.4, 62.8, 342.5, 181.0);
      ctx.closePath();
      ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(137, 137, 137)";
      ctx.fill();

      // layer1/Path
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.moveTo(510.5, 549.8);
      ctx.lineTo(1.9, 549.8);
      ctx.lineTo(1.9, 41.3);
      ctx.lineTo(20.1, 42.5);
      ctx.lineTo(20.1, 532.5);
      ctx.lineTo(510.5, 532.1);
      ctx.lineTo(510.5, 549.8);
      ctx.closePath();
      ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(104, 104, 104)";
      ctx.fill();

      // layer1/Path
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.moveTo(1.9, 41.3);
      ctx.lineTo(510.5, 41.3);
      ctx.lineTo(510.5, 549.8);
      ctx.lineTo(492.3, 532.1);
      ctx.lineTo(492.3, 58.6);
      ctx.lineTo(20.1, 59.0);
      ctx.lineTo(1.9, 41.3);
      ctx.closePath();
      ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(160, 160, 160)";
      ctx.fill();

      // layer1/Compound Path
      ctx.beginPath();

      // layer1/Compound Path/Path
      ctx.moveTo(511.7, 551.0);
      ctx.lineTo(0.7, 551.0);
      ctx.lineTo(0.7, 40.1);
      ctx.lineTo(511.7, 40.1);
      ctx.lineTo(511.7, 551.0);
      ctx.closePath();

      // layer1/Compound Path/Path
      ctx.moveTo(3.1, 548.7);
      ctx.lineTo(509.3, 548.7);
      ctx.lineTo(509.3, 42.4);
      ctx.lineTo(3.1, 42.4);
      ctx.lineTo(3.1, 548.7);
      ctx.closePath();
      ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(0, 0, 0)";
      ctx.fill();
      ctx.restore();
    }


}); // end $(function(){});
</script>

</head>

<body>
    <h3 id="row">Row</h3>
    <h3 id="col">Col</h3>
    <canvas id="canvas" width=513 height=551></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is an exceptional answer!